# Azure Data Factory - Dynamic Skip Lines Expression

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am attempting to import a CSV into ADF however the file header is not the first line of the file. It is dynamic therefore I need to match it based on the first column (e.g "TestID,") which is a string.

Example Data (Header is on Line 4)

```
Date:,01/05/2022
Time:,00:30:25
Test Temperature:,25C
TestID,StartTime,EndTime,Result
TID12345-01,00:45:30,00:47:12,Pass
TID12345-02,00:46:50,00:49:12,Fail
TID12345-03,00:48:20,00:52:17,Pass
TID12345-04,00:49:12,00:49:45,Pass
TID12345-05,00:50:22,00:51:55,Fail
```

I found this article which addresses this issue however I am struggling to rewrite the expression from using an integer to using a string.

https://kromerbigdata.com/2019/09/28/adf-dynamic-skip-lines-find-data-with-variable-headers

First Expression

```
iif(!isNull(toInteger(left(toString(byPosition(1)),1))),toInteger(rownum),toInteger(0))
```

As the article states, this expression looks at the first character of each row and if it is an integer it will return the row number (rownum)

How do I perform this action for a string (e.g "TestID,")

Many Thanks

Jonny

Comment: Hi @JonnyD29, can you please provide the sample data from your file?

Comment: @NiharikaMoola-MT I have updated it with some test file data. Thanks

Comment: What is the target aka sink?

Comment: I've set it up to mirror the article so it is skiplines.csv - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to consider first line that starts with string as your header and preceding lines that starts with numbers should not be considered as header. You can use `isNan` function to check if the first character is Not a number(i.e. string) as seen in the below modified expression:

```
iif(isNan(left(toString(byPosition(1)),1))
    ,toInteger(rownum)
    ,toInteger(0)
   )
```

Following is a breakdown of the above expression:

1. `left(toString(byPosition(1)),1)`: gets first  character fron left side of the first column.
2. `isNan`: checks if the character is "not a number".
3. `iif`: not a number, true then return `rownum`, false then return 0.

Or you can also use functions like `isInteger()` to check if the first character is an integer or not and perform actions accordingly.

Later on as explained in the cited article you need to find minimum `rownum` to skip.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, much appreciated. Although what I am trying to do is return the rownum when the line startsWith "TestID," (would return a 4). However when I attempt to write something like `iif(!isNull(startsWith("TestID"),toInteger(rownum),toInteger(0))` I encounter errors with the expression.

Comment: I think if you include the column name in the expression it should work 
`iif(!isNull(startsWith(Column_Name,"TestID"),toInteger(rownum),toInteger(0))`
In case you are still facing issue provide screenshot of error to better understand how the solution is being implemented.